# How to display collection to template?

Tags: backbone.js

I have been trying to display my data in collection to the template. On my rest console, I can see that the collection is populated; but I am not able to do it in my application. The code is as follows:
In view, the render is like:

```
  render : function() {
                var template = _.template(tpl,{
                       CollectionForTemplate: this.Collection.toJSON(),
                this.el.html(template);

                },
```

In view, the function that calls the fetch is as follows:

```
  loadTariffGrids: function(){
                       //fetch done here
                          if (Collection.length > 0) {
                                _.each(Collection, function(Model) {
                                       JSON.stringify(Model);
                           alert(JSON.stringify(Model));
                                }, this);
                          };
                          this.render;
                       }});


             },
```

And finally, the template is:

```
                       <span>
                       <%  _.each(CollectionForTemplate, function(model) { %>
                       </span>      
                       <td><%= model.cost %></td>

                        <%     }); %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please simply your code, remove any line non-relevant to the issue. Try to work in the most minimal version of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Code is simplified now. Could you please tell me how to pass the collection to the template?

Comment: What is the problem, do you get an error message? Is anything displayed, ....

Comment: No, there is no error message. I am going to try what @Debutante Web Develope suggested,but I donot understand it very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your render, just use:

```
CollectionForTemplate: this.Collection;
```

Modify the view as follows:

```
var self = this;
//fetch done here
if (Collection.length > 0) {
                            _.each(Collection, function(Model) {
                                   JSON.stringify(Model);
                            }, this);
};
self.Collection = Collection;
self.render;
```

I think the collection that you pass to the template was not getting instanciated. So I use self to store the reference before control passes into the fetch function. I know my explanation is not good; I would like someone more experienced to offer you a better explanation. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok @Amateur let's try to solve your need properly.

**Attention**: all code has been written *in the fine air* don't expect it to work just out of the box, use it as inspiration.

First of all is not very good idea to use *programatic logic* in your templates, it is just a design decision, I don't want to look very academic here but I think if you are too flexible with this you can finish with a very difficult to maintenance code.

So, the idea is to manufacture the data so the template has not to make any decision/calculation. And if you need a *loop* into your template let's use sub-templates.

What I understand from your code example is that you have a Collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "cost": 100,
    "name": "Amateur"
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "cost": 200,
    "name": "Other name"
  },

  {
    "id": "3",
    "cost": 300,
    "name": "Other name again"
  },
]
```

And you want to render something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Amateur</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Other name</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Other name again</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As I have read in another (duplicated) question you have sent, you also want to only render `cost` if the `name == "Amateur"`, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Cost</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Amateur</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Other name</td>
    <td>--</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Other name again</td>
    <td>--</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Iteraction

For the iteration we are gonna solve it with sub-templates.

Master template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-elements">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Cost</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</script>
```

Sub-template

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-element">
  <tr>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= cost %></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

In order to make it more *elegant* lets use also a `View` for the `Collection` and a `SubView` for each `Model`.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel
});

var MyModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#template-element").html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

    return this;
  }
});

var MyCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#template-elements").html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template() );

    this.collection.each( function( model ){
      var view = new MyModelView({ model: model });
      this.$el.find( "table" ).append( view.render().el );
    });

    return this;
  }
});
```

#### Decorators

We have solved the iteration issue, now we are gonna implement the logic that hides the `Model.cost` when `Model.name != "Amateur"`.

Let's implement a method that returns the attributes of the `Model` already cooked for the template:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  toJSONCooked: function(){
    var json = this.toJSON();

    if( this.get( "name" ) != "Amateur" ) {
      json.cost = "--";
    }

    return json;
  }
});
```

We can use this method to feed the *template*:

```
var MyModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#template-element").html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSONCooked() ) );

    return this;
  }
});
```